# Spring checkbox JSP Tag is broken when using Converter for type Boolean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo

I've set up a CRUD web application with Spring Roo and Spring MVC. My problem is: since I'm using a converter for localizing the displaying of boolean values the Spring JSP Tag **checkbox** is broken which means the checkboxes don't take the real value from the backing beans. They are always false and unchecked.

I've done some research and probably found the error in the **writeTagDetails** method of **org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.CheckboxTag**. Here is the interesting part of this method:

```
// the concrete type may not be a Boolean - can be String
if (boundValue instanceof String) {
    boundValue = Boolean.valueOf((String) boundValue);
}
Boolean booleanValue = (boundValue != null ? (Boolean) boundValue : Boolean.FALSE);
renderFromBoolean(booleanValue, tagWriter);
```

Because I'm using a converter to display yes/no instead of true/false the **boundValue** is a String and the call of **Boolean.valueOf** always results in false because the **valueOf** method isn't aware of the used Spring Converter and interprets yes/no as false.

How can I solve this issue with Spring? Has anybody a clue? My brain has reached a blind alley.

Just for completeness: The converter for the Boolean type is working as expected (code see below).

```
public class BooleanConverter implements Converter<Boolean,String>, Formatter<Boolean> {

@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;

@Override
public String print(Boolean object, Locale locale) {
    return (object)
            ? messageSource.getMessage("label_true", null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale())
            : messageSource.getMessage("label_false", null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
}

@Override
public String convert(Boolean source) {
    return this.print(source, null);
}
}
```

Comment: I don't know Spring MVC very well, so pardon me if my question is stupid. But what's the point of a boolean converter? I understand the need for dates or even numbers, which are entered as strings by the end user in text fields. But A user never directly enters a boolean, does he?

Comment: Such a converter is used for displaying the localized form of yes/no instead of true/false. So it's only for displaying boolean values. The input is done via a normal checkbox.

Comment: But shouldn't you do an explicit formatting (using the fmt:message tag, for example) when displaying a boolean value? Reading the Spring doc, it seems that converters are used for data-binding (i.e. to bind the value attribute of a checkbox or radio button, for example), but not for displaying text (i.e. the label of the checkbox or radio button). Since value attributes of checkboxes and radio buttons are never displayed to the user, why use a converter here? How do you do to display "yes" or "no" from a boolean value?

Comment: The boolean value is displayed via a table or display tag (both Spring JSP Tags), for instance. Those tags you only give the bean and property as an input. Without this converter the user would see there alot of 'true' and 'false'.

Comment: OK. I see now. I didn't know those tags existed. And I've been unable to find them in the documentation. Your question makes more sense to me now. I would ask in a spring forum ans maybe file a bug report if I were you. This looks like a bug to me. Thanks for your explanations. Sorry for being unable to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems possible to overcome.  That is you want a human readable Formatter to display yes/no to the user for boolean values in the model.  But you still want the checkbox HTML elements to work and it appears those HTML checkbox elements/widgets/JSP tags expects true/false string to be used (or a boolean Java type) it doesn't appear to use the converter to get the arbitrary yes/no string back to a boolean type.

This problem for me manifests itself as the initial state of the checkbox is never ticked when the model has a Boolean.TRUE value set.  This means any read-modify-update of the record (without editing that field ends up transitioning from 'true' to 'false' when it was not changed by the user).  This is due to the initial state in the UI being inconsistent with the model (it shows always unchecked i.e. false state) even when model is true state.  The displayed value is of an unchecked checkbox in the HTML edit record screen, even when the model has Boolean.TRUE for that value.  This is because "yes" does not get interpreted as "true" by the HTML checkbox elements and it defaults to false (as that is the default boolean value).

So define your Formatter/Converter (as you are already doing).  But in your @Controller add:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Boolean.class, "friesWithThat", new CustomBooleanEditor(false));
}
```

This appears to make the string display value continue to be yes/no but the value used and passed to the checkbox HTML elements continues to be true/false.

Now when editing/updating the record (in CRUD) the initial state of the checkbox is consistent with the model and saving the data (without editing any fields) does not transition the checkbox state (which is my understanding of the problem you have).

So from this I think we can understand that Converters/Formatters are for general display of data and that PropertyEditors are for mapping model data so the data needed by the UI widget.

Comment: See below for a general purpose version that doesn't need the field names.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should write your own type called `Choice` which has `Choice.YES` and `Choice.NO` as ordinal enumerations which correspond to 1 or 0 based on the values stored in the database.

Then you can have your own display tags and input tags defined within the application for this type which would address this issue.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the hint to use an enum. That's probably the best way to go at the moment. I will also express this question (or problem, we'll see) on the spring forum.

Comment: and wish you all the best with Spring Roo too. :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the previous answer, from spring 3.2 you can register the property editor for all controllers and all Boolean fields like this:

```
package your.package.path;

import org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomBooleanEditor;
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;

@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalBindingInitializer {

    @InitBinder
    public void registerCustomEditors(WebDataBinder binder, WebRequest request) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Boolean.class, new CustomBooleanEditor(false));
    }
}
```

if you are coming from Spring Roo basic configuration remember also to add this line in your webmvc-config.xml

```
    <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice" type="annotation"/>
```

like this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="your.package.path" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
    <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice" type="annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

Comment: For modern Spring, you seem to need to register the customer editor for Boolean.class (the object) and boolean.class (the primitive).  Other than that, it worked like a charm.