# Spring display format vs editing format

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, formatting

## Background

I have a small Spring MVC web project (with standard JSPs as the view engine), and I decided that it would be nice if boolean values could be displayed as "yes" or "no" - I think that looks more friendly than "true" and "false". So I created a custom `BooleanFormatter` to do this for me. So far, so good.

However, when a boolean field is rendered as a checkbox, Spring does the following to determine if the checkbox should be checked:

1. Convert the boolean value to "yes" or "no".
2. Check the result of applying `Boolean.valueOf` to this.

Of course, `Boolean.valueOf("yes")` is `false`, and so checkboxes will never be rendered as checked.

This is a problem.

## My Question

Is there a way to tell Spring that a formatter should *only* be used when displaying a value, and not when rendering (or parsing the value of) an editor?

(I'm looking for something similar to ASP.NET MVC's DisplayTemplate vs EditorTemplate, or `DisplayFormat.ApplyFormatInEditMode`)

Or, am I going about this the wrong way completely?

Comment: Ok, I found the answer to my exact problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6575542/5317869
But I still want to ask the question about a distinction between display format and edit format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into the code of `AbstractPropertyBindingResult`, to see why the answer to [Spring checkbox JSP Tag is broken when using Converter for type Boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6575542/5317869) worked. This is the code used when rendering a checkbox/other input:

```
protected Object formatFieldValue(String field, @Nullable Object value) {
    String fixedField = fixedField(field);
    // Try custom editor...
    PropertyEditor customEditor = getCustomEditor(fixedField);
    if (customEditor != null) {
        customEditor.setValue(value);
        String textValue = customEditor.getAsText();
        // If the PropertyEditor returned null, there is no appropriate
        // text representation for this value: only use it if non-null.
        if (textValue != null) {
            return textValue;
        }
    }
    if (this.conversionService != null) {
        // Try custom converter...
        TypeDescriptor fieldDesc = getPropertyAccessor().getPropertyTypeDescriptor(fixedField);
        TypeDescriptor strDesc = TypeDescriptor.valueOf(String.class);
        if (fieldDesc != null && this.conversionService.canConvert(fieldDesc, strDesc)) {
            return this.conversionService.convert(value, fieldDesc, strDesc);
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

During data binding, a similar process is followed, of

1. Try to find a `PropertyEditor`.
2. Try to find a `Converter`/`Formatter`

Therefore:

- To specify a format for editors only, use a `PropertyEditor`.
- To specify a format for display only, use a `Formatter` or `Converter`, but also use a `PropertyEditor` to do the default behaviour.